# How to Make sure only the First Record is Selected from a particular table have which can Mutiple Records of Same ID in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, cobol

I am trying to Selected a specific event from a event able, which can have mutile records with same ID.

SQL query is something like this:

```
EXEC SQL
  SELECT ID, 
         NAME, 
         DATE, 
         TIME
    FROM EVENT 
   WHERE ID   = 100  
     AND NAME = 'John'
END-EXEC.
```

Query Result can be with Multiple records.

Result set:

```
ID    NAME    DATE       TIME
100   JOHN    2021-06-06 12.11.23
100   JOHN    2021-06-09 12.11.23
100   JOHN    2021-06-07 12.11.23
```

this is causing -811 to which i am continue my program logic.
here i want to select the Latest Event i.e. 100   JOHN    2021-06-09 12.11.23

hence i applied ORDER BY clause.

```
EXEC SQL
  SELECT ID, 
         NAME, 
         DATE, 
         TIME
    FROM EVENT 
   WHERE ID   = 100  
     AND NAME = 'John'
   ORDER BY DATE DESC,
            TIME DESC 
END-EXEC.
```

which fetches Result set as:

```
ID    NAME    DATE       TIME
100   JOHN    2021-06-09 12.11.23
100   JOHN    2021-06-07 12.11.23
100   JOHN    2021-06-06 12.11.23
```

hence the first records that will be selected with be the 100   JOHN    2021-06-09 12.11.23,
but strangly when i run the program, the second event i.e.100   JOHN    2021-06-07 12.11.23
is selected.

my requirnment is to have selected the latest event hecne i am orderning it by DESC, but still
there is no success. Please Advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your queries are not valid SQL statements -- although perhaps your interface fixes that.  You want `AND` in the `WHERE` clause rather than `,`.

Second, you can fetch just one row using `FETCH FIRST`.  So:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, DATE,  TIME
FROM EVENT 
WHERE ID = 100 AND NAME = 'John'
ORDER BY DATE DESC, TIME DESC 
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: okay, thanks Gordon, i edited my previous post with AND clause now. Sure i will try implement this solution, before i go ahead, just want to confirm will i need any cursor to Enable the FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY?

Comment: When using `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` you will not need a cursor but can do a direct `SELECT ... INTO ...`

Comment: Thanks, i implemented these and the SELECT INTO with FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY is worked.